# Accessing browser's local assets (like an image) via URL?

Tags: javascript, url, browser

There is an API I'd like to interact with. It takes URL of an image and does it's thing. The problem is that I can't specify URL of an image saved in my clipboard for example.

Is there a way to make the browser behave like a file server in the sense that the outside Internet can access browser's assets via URL without creating your own backend. What would be the easiest and painless solution?

Comment: Are you asking if you can send the contents of your clipboard as an actual file to an API?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would `data:` URLs suit your purpose? You can convert uploaded files and clipboard images without any backend requirements. Check if your API supports them.

Comment: If you could, this would become a pretty big security issue. if this is a one-off thing you can with 2 command line tools (`python` and `ngrok`) expose any directory on your machine to the internet though.